# Postgresql: Calculate time difference between elements of a column for an element

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Assuming I have the following table:

```
id | elementID | date | time
----------------------------
```

What I search is the following:

1. select all "time"-Values for a given elementID order by date,time (this is easy)
2. Calculate the time difference between the time-values

The second point causes problems because I dont know where to start. In c++ I would iterate with a loop over all "times" and simple calculate

```
dt = time_i - time_{i-1}
e.g.
00:00:57 - 00:00:30 = 27s = dt
00:01:05 - 00:00:57 =  8s = dt
00:01:09 - 00:01:05 =  4s = dt
etc.
```

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want the `lag` window function.

```
SELECT time_col - lag(time_col) OVER (ORDER BY whatever)
FROM the_table
ORDER BY whatever;
```

See the [window function tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) and the [user manual page for window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) . The `lag` window function lets you get the "previous" row in a result set in the current result set and use it in expressions.

Comment: This seems to work brilliant. Those Window functions where exactly what I was looking for

Comment: One last question: How can I convert the results from time to seconds, e.g.  00:01:05 -> 65s. I tried the following: SELECT (EXTRACT(epoch from (time_col - lag(time_col)))) OVER (ORDER BY whatever)
FROM the_table where conditions   But I get the error that im trying to extract from a table, not from a single value

Comment: @Anonymous Please post a new question showing: Exact code, exact error, and exact PostgreSQL version. Link back to this one for context if you like. At a quick look I think you're trying to apply the window to `extract` as a whole.